# Libav: Find out the exact time that the first frame coming from an RTSP stream was dumped into a file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, synchronization

I am dumping an RSTP stream from a web camera into a file using `avconv`:

```
avconv -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user@password/
192.168.1.4/stream.cgi -t 100 -c:v libx264 -s 1024x768 -an
/home/borrajax/Videos/capture.mp4
```

When I execute the command above, `avconv` seems to wait for a few... seconds (if so) and then starts recording. I'm guessing it's buffering and/or waiting
for a keyframe.

I'd like to know if I can get the exact time when the first frame was dumped into the destination file. (milliseconds, if it were possible) I need to synchronize the video with some other timestamped events, and I need it to be as precise as possible.

Another workaround that would work great for me would be (instead of trying to get the exact time of the first frame) telling `avconv` something like "*do whatever buffering or waiting that you need to do, but make sure the first frame is dumped at EXACTLY this time*". Although that seems a bit more difficult to do.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS` (64 bit) and `libav-tools` Version: 4:0.8.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (with `libavcodec-extra-53` and `libavutil-extra-51` installed)